# sudo requests password in one system, not in another, same configuration, what is the fix?

Tags: sudo

Two systems, one Ubuntu 18.04, the other Ubuntu server 20.04, have exactly the same `/etc/sudoers` configuration, yet `sudo` behaves differently.

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Users and groups are slightly different (user "a" vs. user "b" in the two systems, but same uid & gid), and I fail to see how their group associations are different with respect to sudo. Both are in the adm and sudo groups, neither is in the root or admin group (in my U18.04 there is no admin group; the admin group is empty on U20.04).

In my U18.04 system, sudo requires a password, except for 15 minutes after having entered a password, as expected.

In my U20.04 system, sudo does not ever request a password.

**Q:** What do I need to do to enforce password entry on my U20.04 system (except for 15 minutes after previous entry)?

Comment: Run `sudo -l` as the user on both systems and compare the output.

Comment: Very useful indeed, U20.04 shows two rules matched: `(ALL : ALL) ALL` and `(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Found it in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`. I removed the line in there, and it works instantly, thank you.